# how to delete adjacent entries from a set while iterating over it

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, set

How can I erase all adjacent entries from a set while iterating over the set.  In my case I have a custom comparator that defines adjacent entries as those that differ by 1 from left to right.  Thus for the set `std::set<int> mySet = {1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10}` I would like to remove the entries `{1,2,3,4,5,9,10}` as these satisfy my comparator. (note the 7 is left as it is the only one in the series is not one of the elements in an adjacent pair.

The code below (also in [**coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d323a359de7c0675)) shows that I can find add the adjacent entries correctly, however if I try to erase both the left side of the adjacent pair `adjIter` and also the right side `*std::next(adjIter)` the code crashes with an invalid iterator.

```
int main() {    
    std::set<int> mySet = {1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10};
    static const auto gPred = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return rhs == lhs+1;
    };
    auto adjIter = mySet.begin();
    std::set<int> adjacentEntries;
    while ((adjIter = std::adjacent_find(adjIter, mySet.end(),
        gPred)) != mySet.end()) {
        adjacentEntries.insert(*adjIter);
        // peek at the second entry that should be 1 greater than adjIter        
        adjacentEntries.insert(*std::next(adjIter));
        // how do I erase both *std::next(adjIter) & adjIter
        ++adjIter;
    }
    std::cout << adjacentEntries << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach of continuing the save and delete of elements while the predicate is true.

```
void remove_adjacent_entries()
{
    std::set<int> mySet = { 1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10 };
    static const auto gPred = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return rhs == lhs + 1;
    };

    auto adjIter = mySet.begin();
    std::set<int> adjacentEntries;
    while ((adjIter = std::adjacent_find(adjIter, mySet.end(), gPred)) != mySet.end()) {
        for (auto next = std::next(adjIter); next != mySet.end() && gPred(*adjIter, *next); ++next) {
            //save and delete the first of the pair of elements found
            adjacentEntries.insert(*adjIter);
            mySet.erase(adjIter++);
        }
        //save and delete the second element
        adjacentEntries.insert(*adjIter);
        mySet.erase(adjIter++);
    }
    //print
    for(auto& i : adjacentEntries)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: nice work!  Looks like you got it right, I have been struggling with this algorithm for a couple of days

Answer (score 1):

Answering to:

> The code below (also in coliru) shows that I can find add the adjacent entries correctly, however if I try to erase both the left side of the adjacent pair adjIter and also the right side *std::next(adjIter) the code crashes with an invalid iterator.

C++11 onwards (as you are using `auto`s, I guess this is good enough):

[set::erase(const_iterator first, const_iterator last)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) - see (2)nd form as it *returns an iterator pointing past the last element deleted.*

So I guess it'd be:

```
while ((adjIter = std::adjacent_find(adjIter, mySet.end(), gPred)) != mySet.end()) {
    adjacentEntries.insert(*adjIter);
    // peek at the second entry that should be 1 greater than adjIter        
    adjacentEntries.insert(*std::next(adjIter));

    // here's how to erase both *std::next(adjIter) & adjIter
    adjIter=mySet.erase(adjIter, std::next(std::next(adjIter)));
}
```

**Note:** the code above no longer crashes but has an algorithmic bug, in the example provided, **5 will not be removed** (because 4 will be removed by 3 before), but that's beyond the question (or do you want me to find a solution for that too?) - [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc07c13efa3ef022).

---

Correct solution: removes all the numbers preceded by num-1 or succeeded by num+1. In the example of `{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10}` only `7` will remain in `mySet`.

[See it on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/005428dc5107b529)

```
int main() {    
    std::set<int> mySet = {1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10};
    static const auto gPred = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return rhs == lhs+1;
    };
    std::set<int> adjacentEntries;

    auto adjIter = mySet.begin();
    auto prevDelete = mySet.end();

    while ((adjIter = std::adjacent_find(adjIter, mySet.end(), gPred)) != mySet.end()) {
        adjacentEntries.insert(*adjIter);
        // peek at the second entry that should be 1 greater than adjIter        
        adjacentEntries.insert(*std::next(adjIter));
        if(prevDelete!=adjIter && prevDelete!=mySet.end()) {
          // the prevDelete is the rhs of a pair which is followed by a "hole"
          mySet.erase(prevDelete, std::next(prevDelete));
        }
        prevDelete=mySet.end();

        // erase the lhs but delay the erasure of rhs,
        // let rhs participaye in the next round of search
        adjIter=mySet.erase(adjIter, std::next(adjIter));
        prevDelete=adjIter;
    }
    if(prevDelete!=mySet.end()) {
      mySet.erase(prevDelete, std::next(prevDelete));
    }
    std::cout << adjacentEntries << std::endl;
    std::cout << mySet << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Great, btw the 5 is left in if I increment the iterator after the erasure, see the updated coliru http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/680599974ca1aeff do you see any problem with this approach?

Comment: @johnco3 "Great, btw the 5 is left in if I increment the iterator after the erasure" Are you sure? It was left in the code in my answer, but I thought you would want it removed. "do you see any problem with this approach?" Yes, in your example the effect of `adjIter++` is the code jumps over 3 (which is followed by 4 and should be removed)

Comment: @johnco3 See corrected solution - has linky on coliru as well

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to use extra space** for set `adjacentEntries`. You can achieve it by using a flag `del` (*when to erase the previous iterator*), with `O(1)` space complexity in much simpler way:

```
std::set<int>::iterator prevItr = mySet.begin(), nextItr, currItr;
int prevVal = *prevItr;
int del = 0;
currItr = next(mySet.begin());
while (currItr != mySet.end()) {
    nextItr = std::next(currItr);
    if(prevVal+1 == *currItr || del == 1){
        mySet.erase(prevItr);
        if(prevVal+1 == *currItr) del = 1;
        else del = 0;
    }
    prevItr = currItr;
    prevVal = *currItr;
    currItr = next(currItr);
}
if(del == 1){
    mySet.erase(prevItr);
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Jgdej8)